# Is this version of evaluation homomorphism theorem correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

The theorem comes from Kostrikin's Introduction to Algebra and goes as follows:

> If $A$ (a commutative ring with an identity) is a subring of a commutative ring $R$, then for every element $t \in R$ there exists exactly one homomorphism $\Pi_t: A[X] \rightarrow R$, such that $\Pi_t(X)=t$ and $\Pi_t(a)=a$ for every $a \in A$.

I'm having some doubts about my understanding of this. If we set $A=\{(a, 0): a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, $R=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $t=(0,1)$, then these fulfil all requirements of the theorem if we define operations on them as $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a+c, b+d)$ and $(a, b)(c,d)=(ac, bd)$. Therefore the described homomorphism should exist. However, my "counterexample" to that would be:

$(0,0)=(1,0)(0,1)=\Pi_{(0,1)}((1,0))\Pi_{(0,1)}(X)=\Pi_{(0,1)}((1,0)X)=\Pi_{(0,1)}(X)=(0,1)$

So that shows that something here isn't quite right.

Comment: Depending on your definition, $A$ is not a subring of $R$, since the identity of $A$ must be the identity of $R$.

Comment: @PaulK I think that sounds right. It seems that Kostrikin indeed includes that requirement into the definition of a subring. So the theorem doesn't hold if we don't require the identity of $A$ to be the identity of $R$?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. For example you could also take the zero ring $A = \{0\} \subseteq R$ for some non-trivial ring $R$. Then $A[X] = \{0\}$ and there is no (or only one) homomorphism $A[X] \to R$ (depending on your definition of ring homomorphism).

Answer (score 1):

The problem step seems to be $\Pi_{(0,1)}((1,0)X)=\Pi_{(0,1)}(X)$. Indeed, $(1,0)$ is not the multiplicative identity in $\Bbb Z^2$; that role belongs to $(1,1)$.

Comment: But isn't it the multiplicative identity in $A[X]$?

Comment: The multiplicative identity in $R[X]$ is the same as the multiplicative identity in $R$. (For example, the multiplicative identity in $\Bbb R[X]$ is the constant polynomial $1$.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you write

$$\Pi_{(0,1)}((1,0)X)=\Pi_{(0,1)}(X)$$

I imagine that you suppose that $(1,0)X=X$. Which might not be the case.

Comment: But isn't $(1,0)$ the multiplicative identity in $A[X]$?

Comment: See Paul K comment.